# ViewModel does not save recyclerview data when on configuration changed (device rotate)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I just noticed problem earlier in my app, I see the ViewModel inside fragment doesn't save/keep recycler view when I rotate the device, I don't want to use the old method like save data in bundle `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it, I tried to figure why this problem by printing some logs on each method in fragment lifecycle but I didn't succeed

**GIF showing the problem**

[image]

**the ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class PostViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepository: MainRepository,
    private val dataStoreRepository: DataStoreRepository,
    application: Application
) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {


    /** ROOM DATABASE */
    val readAllPosts: LiveData<List<Item>> = mainRepository.localDataSource.getAllItems().asLiveData()
    val postsBySearchInDB: MutableLiveData<List<Item>> = MutableLiveData()

    /** RETROFIT **/
    var postsResponse: MutableLiveData<NetworkResult<PostList>> = MutableLiveData()
    var searchedPostsResponse: MutableLiveData<NetworkResult<PostList>> = MutableLiveData()

    var postListResponse: PostList? = null

    var postListByLabelResponse: PostList? = null

    var searchPostListResponse: PostList? = null

    val label = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var finalURL: MutableLiveData<String?> = MutableLiveData()
    val token = MutableLiveData<String?>()

    val currentDestination = MutableLiveData<Int>()


    fun getCurrentDestination() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreRepository.readCurrentDestination.collect {
                currentDestination.value = it
            }

        }
    }

    val errorCode = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val searchError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    var networkStats = false
    var backOnline = false

    val recyclerViewLayout = dataStoreRepository.readRecyclerViewLayout.asLiveData()
    val readBackOnline = dataStoreRepository.readBackOnline.asLiveData()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        finalURL.value = null
        token.value = null
    }


    private fun saveBackOnline(backOnline: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        dataStoreRepository.saveBackOnline(backOnline)
    }

    fun saveCurrentDestination(currentDestination: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreRepository.saveCurrentDestination(currentDestination)
        }
    }

    fun saveRecyclerViewLayout(layout: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreRepository.saveRecyclerViewLayout(layout)
        }
    }


    fun getPosts() = viewModelScope.launch {
        getPostsSafeCall()
    }

    fun getPostListByLabel() = viewModelScope.launch {
        getPostsByLabelSafeCall()
    }

    fun getItemsBySearch() = viewModelScope.launch {
        getItemsBySearchSafeCall()
    }

    private suspend fun getPostsByLabelSafeCall() {
        postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Loading()

        if (hasInternetConnection()) {
            try {

                val response = mainRepository.remoteDataSource.getPostListByLabel(finalURL.value!!)
                postsResponse.value = handlePostsByLabelResponse(response)

            } catch (ex: HttpException) {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.message + ex.cause)
                postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error(ex.message.toString())
                errorCode.value = ex.code()

            } catch (ex: NullPointerException) {
                postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error("There's no items")
            }
        } else {
            postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error("No Internet Connection.")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getPostsSafeCall() {
        postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Loading()
        if (hasInternetConnection()) {
            try {

                if (finalURL.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    finalURL.value = "$BASE_URL?key=$API_KEY"
                }

                val response = mainRepository.remoteDataSource.getPostList(finalURL.value!!)
                postsResponse.value = handlePostsResponse(response)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error(e.message.toString())

                if (e is HttpException) {
                    errorCode.value = e.code()
                    Log.e(TAG, "getPostsSafeCall: errorCode $errorCode")
                    Log.e(TAG, "getPostsSafeCall: ${e.message.toString()}")
                }
            }
        } else {
            postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error("No Internet Connection.")
        }
    }


    private fun handlePostsResponse(response: Response<PostList>): NetworkResult<PostList> {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {

            if (!(token.value.equals(response.body()?.nextPageToken))) {
                token.value = response.body()?.nextPageToken

                response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                    Log.d(
                        TAG, "handlePostsResponse: old token is: ${token.value} " +
                                "new token is: ${resultResponse.nextPageToken}"
                    )


                    finalURL.value = "${BASE_URL}?pageToken=${token.value}&key=${API_KEY}"

                    Log.e(TAG, "handlePostsResponse finalURL is ${finalURL.value!!}")

                    for (item in resultResponse.items) {
                        insertItem(item)
                    }
                    return NetworkResult.Success(resultResponse)
                    

                }
            }



        }
        if (token.value == null) {
            errorCode.value = 400
        } else {
            errorCode.value = response.code()
        }

        return NetworkResult.Error(
            "network results of handlePostsResponse ${
                response.body().toString()
            }"
        )
    }

    private fun handlePostsByLabelResponse(response: Response<PostList>): NetworkResult<PostList> {

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                Log.d(
                    TAG, "handlePostsByLabelResponse: old token is: ${token.value} " +
                            "new token is: ${resultResponse.nextPageToken}"
                )

                finalURL.postValue(
                    (BASE_URL_POSTS_BY_LABEL + "posts?labels=${label.value}"
                            + "&maxResults=20"
                            + "&pageToken=")
                            + token.value
                            + "&key=" + API_KEY
                )

                if (postListByLabelResponse == null) {
                    postListByLabelResponse = resultResponse
                } else {
                    val oldPosts = postListByLabelResponse?.items
                    val newPosts = resultResponse.items
                    oldPosts?.addAll(newPosts)
                }



                return NetworkResult.Success(postListByLabelResponse?:resultResponse)


            }
        }
        if (token.value == null) {
            errorCode.value = 400
        } else {
            errorCode.value = response.code()
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "handlePostsByLabelResponse: final URL ${finalURL.value}")
  

        return NetworkResult.Error(
            "network results of handlePostsByLabelResponse ${
                response.body().toString()
            }"
        )
    }


    private fun hasInternetConnection(): Boolean {

        val connectivityManager = getApplication<Application>().getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
        ) as ConnectivityManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val capabilities =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork) ?: return false
            return when {
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
        }

    }

    fun showNetworkStats() {
        if (!networkStats) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "No Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            saveBackOnline(true)
        } else if (networkStats) {
            if (backOnline) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "We're back online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                saveBackOnline(false)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun insertItem(item: Item) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mainRepository.localDataSource.insertItem(item)
        }
    }



    private suspend fun getItemsBySearchSafeCall() {
        searchedPostsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Loading()
        if (!label.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            finalURL.value = "${BASE_URL}?labels=${label.value}&maxResults=500&key=$API_KEY"
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "getItemsBySearch: ${finalURL.value}")

        if (hasInternetConnection()) {
            try {
                val response = mainRepository.remoteDataSource.getPostListBySearch(finalURL.value!!)

                searchedPostsResponse.value = handlePostsBySearchResponse(response)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                searchedPostsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error(e.message.toString())
            }
        } else {
            searchedPostsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Error("No Internet Connection.")
        }

    }

    private fun handlePostsBySearchResponse(response: Response<PostList>): NetworkResult<PostList> {
        return if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val postListResponse = response.body()
            NetworkResult.Success(postListResponse!!)
        } else {
            errorCode.value = response.code()
            NetworkResult.Error(response.errorBody().toString())

        }
    }


    fun getItemsBySearchInDB(keyword: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemsBySearchInDB: called")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val items = mainRepository.localDataSource.getItemsBySearch(keyword)
            if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
                postsBySearchInDB.value = items
            } else {
                searchError.value = true
                Log.e(TAG, "list is empty")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**the fragment**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AccessoryFragment : Fragment(), MenuProvider, TitleAndGridLayout {

    private var _binding: FragmentAccessoryBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    private var searchItemList = arrayListOf<Item>()
    private lateinit var postViewModel: PostViewModel


    private val titleLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager by lazy { GridLayoutManager(context, 2) }
    private val gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager by lazy { GridLayoutManager(context, 3) }
    private var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null

    private val KEY_RECYCLER_STATE = "recycler_state"
    private val mBundleRecyclerViewState by lazy { Bundle() }

    private lateinit var adapter: PostAdapter

    private var isScrolling = false
    var currentItems = 0
    var totalItems: Int = 0
    var scrollOutItems: Int = 0
    private var postsAPiFlag = false

    private var keyword: String? = null
    private lateinit var networkListener: NetworkListener
    
    private var networkStats = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        postViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[PostViewModel::class.java]
        adapter = PostAdapter(this)

        postViewModel.finalURL.value =
            BASE_URL_POSTS_BY_LABEL + "posts?labels=Accessory&maxResults=20&key=$API_KEY"

        networkListener = NetworkListener()

    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentAccessoryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.CREATED)

        postViewModel.label.value = "Accessory"

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: called")

        postViewModel.recyclerViewLayout.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { layout ->

            linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            Log.w(TAG, "onViewCreated getSavedLayout called")
            when (layout) {
                "cardLayout" -> {
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
                    adapter.viewType = 0
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                }
                "cardMagazineLayout" -> {
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
                    adapter.viewType = 1
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                }
                "titleLayout" -> {
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = titleLayoutManager
                    adapter.viewType = 2
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                }
                "gridLayout" -> {
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
                    adapter.viewType = 3
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            networkListener.checkNetworkAvailability(requireContext()).collect { stats ->
                Log.d(TAG, "networkListener: $stats")
                postViewModel.networkStats = stats
                postViewModel.showNetworkStats()
                this@AccessoryFragment.networkStats = stats
                if (stats ) {

                    if (binding.accessoryRecyclerView.visibility == View.GONE) {
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    requestApiData()


                } else {

//                    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: savedInstanceState $savedInstanceState")
                    noInternetConnectionLayout()
                }
            }
        }

        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.onItemClick { _, position, _ ->
            val postItem = adapter.differ.currentList[position]
            findNavController().navigate(
                AccessoryFragmentDirections.actionNavAccessoryToDetailsActivity(
                    postItem
                )
            )
        }



        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true
                }

            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)



                currentItems = linearLayoutManager!!.childCount
                totalItems = adapter.itemCount
                scrollOutItems = linearLayoutManager!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                if ((!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && dy > 0) &&
                    (isScrolling && currentItems + scrollOutItems >= totalItems && postsAPiFlag)
                ) {
                    hideShimmerEffect()
                    postViewModel.getPostListByLabel()
                    isScrolling = false
                }
            }
        })

        postViewModel.errorCode.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { errorCode ->
            if (errorCode == 400) {
                binding.accessoryRecyclerView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), R.string.lastPost, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${postViewModel.errorCode.value.toString()} ")
                noInternetConnectionLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: ${newConfig.orientation}")

        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: ${adapter.differ.currentList.toString()}")
        Log.d(
            TAG,
            "onConfigurationChanged: " +
                    binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager?.itemCount.toString()
        )

    }

 
    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored: called")
    }

    private fun requestApiData() {
        showShimmerEffect()
        Log.d(TAG, "requestApiData: called")
        postViewModel.getPostListByLabel()
        postViewModel.postsResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
            postsAPiFlag = true
            when (response) {
                is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                    hideShimmerEffect()
                    response.data?.let {
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

//                        itemArrayList.addAll(it.items)
                        adapter.differ.submitList(it.items.toList())

                    }

                }

                is NetworkResult.Error -> {
                    hideShimmerEffect()
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                    Log.e(TAG, response.data.toString())
                    Log.e(TAG, response.message.toString())
                }

                is NetworkResult.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                }
            }

        }
    }


    private fun showShimmerEffect() {
        binding.apply {
            shimmerLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            accessoryRecyclerView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }

    }

    private fun hideShimmerEffect() {
        binding.apply {
            shimmerLayout.stopShimmer()
            shimmerLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            accessoryRecyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun changeAndSaveLayout() {
        Log.w(TAG, "changeAndSaveLayout: called")
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_layout))
        val recyclerViewLayouts = resources.getStringArray(R.array.RecyclerViewLayouts)
        //        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        builder.setItems(
            recyclerViewLayouts
        ) { _: DialogInterface?, index: Int ->
            try {
                when (index) {
                    0 -> {
                        adapter.viewType = 0
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        postViewModel.saveRecyclerViewLayout("cardLayout")
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        adapter.viewType = 1
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        postViewModel.saveRecyclerViewLayout("cardMagazineLayout")

                    }
                    2 -> {
                        adapter.viewType = 2
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = titleLayoutManager
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        postViewModel.saveRecyclerViewLayout("titleLayout")
                    }
                    3 -> {
                        adapter.viewType = 3
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
                        binding.accessoryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

                        postViewModel.saveRecyclerViewLayout("gridLayout")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "changeAndSaveLayout: " + e.message)
                Log.e(TAG, "changeAndSaveLayout: " + e.cause)
            }
        }
        val alertDialog = builder.create()
        alertDialog.show()
    }


    private fun noInternetConnectionLayout() {
        binding.apply {
//            accessoryRecyclerView.removeAllViews()
            Log.d(TAG, "noInternetConnectionLayout: called")
            shimmerLayout.stopShimmer()
            shimmerLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            accessoryRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        binding.noInternetConnectionLayout.inflate()

        binding.noInternetConnectionLayout.let {
            if (networkStats) {
                it.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
//        adapter.isDestroyed = true
        linearLayoutManager?.removeAllViews()
//        adView.destroy()
        linearLayoutManager = null
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        if(linearLayoutManager != null){
            linearLayoutManager = null
        }
    }

    override fun tellFragmentToGetItems() {
        if (postViewModel.recyclerViewLayout.value.equals("titleLayout")
            || postViewModel.recyclerViewLayout.value.equals("gridLayout")
        ) {
            hideShimmerEffect()
            postViewModel.getPostListByLabel()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        val searchManager =
            requireContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(requireActivity().componentName))
        searchView.queryHint = resources.getString(R.string.searchForPosts)



        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(keyword: String): Boolean {
                if (keyword.isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        requireView(),
                        "please enter keyword to search",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
//                itemArrayList.clear()
                this@AccessoryFragment.keyword = keyword
                requestSearchApi(keyword)

                return false

            }


            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
        searchView.setOnCloseListener {
            if (keyword.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                hideShimmerEffect()
                return@setOnCloseListener false
            }
            if (Utils.hasInternetConnection(requireContext())) {
                showShimmerEffect()

                postViewModel.postListByLabelResponse = null

                searchItemList.clear()
//                adapter.differ.submitList(ArrayList())

                linearLayoutManager?.removeAllViews()
                binding.accessoryRecyclerView.removeAllViews()

//                itemArrayList.clear()
                adapter.differ.submitList(null)

                postViewModel.finalURL.value =
                    BASE_URL_POSTS_BY_LABEL + "posts?labels=Accessory&maxResults=20&key=$API_KEY"

                requestApiData()


//                itemArrayList.clear()
//                adapter.submitList(itemArrayList)


                //====> Here I call the request api method again


                Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    "setOnCloseListener: called ${adapter.differ.currentList.size.toString()}"
                )
//                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
//                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
//


                Log.d(TAG, "setOnCloseListener: ${postViewModel.finalURL.value.toString()}")
//
//                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
//                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "setOnCloseListener: called")
                adapter.differ.submitList(null)
                searchItemList.clear()
                noInternetConnectionLayout()
            }
            false
        }


        postViewModel.searchError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { searchError ->
            if (searchError) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "There's no posts with this keyword", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestSearchApi(keyword: String) {

        if (Utils.hasInternetConnection(requireContext())) {
            showShimmerEffect()

            postViewModel.finalURL.value =
                "${BASE_URL}?labels=Accessory&maxResults=500&key=$API_KEY"

            postViewModel.getItemsBySearch()
            postViewModel.searchedPostsResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
                when (response) {
                    is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                        postsAPiFlag = false
                        //                                adapter.differ.currentList.clear()

                        if (searchItemList.isNotEmpty()) {
                            searchItemList.clear()
                        }

                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                        lifecycleScope.launch {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                                searchItemList.addAll(response.data?.items?.filter {
                                    it.title.contains(keyword) || it.content.contains(keyword)
                                } as ArrayList<Item>)
                            }
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "requestSearchApi: test size ${searchItemList.size}")


                        if (searchItemList.isEmpty()) {
//                                adapter.differ.submitList(null)
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "The search word was not found in any post",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            hideShimmerEffect()
                            return@observe

                        } else {
                            postsAPiFlag = false
//                            itemArrayList.clear()
                            adapter.differ.submitList(null)

                            hideShimmerEffect()
//                            Log.d(
////                                TAG, "requestSearchApi: searchItemList ${searchItemList[0].title}"
//                            )
                            adapter.differ.submitList(searchItemList)
//                            binding.accessoryRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
                        }

                    }
                    is NetworkResult.Error -> {
                        hideShimmerEffect()
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            response.message.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        Log.e(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: $response")

                    }

                    is NetworkResult.Loading -> {
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            noInternetConnectionLayout()
        }
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return if (menuItem.itemId == R.id.change_layout) {
            changeAndSaveLayout()
            true
        } else false
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something (that's a lot of code to go through!) you don't set any data on your adapter until this bit:

```
private fun requestApiData() {
    postViewModel.getPostListByLabel()
    postViewModel.postsResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        ...
        adapter.differ.submitList(it.items.toList())
}
```

And `getPostListByLabel()` clears the current data in `postsResponse`

```
fun getPostListByLabel() = viewModelScope.launch {
    getPostsByLabelSafeCall()
}

private suspend fun getPostsByLabelSafeCall() {
    postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Loading()
    // fetch data over network and update postsResponse with it later
    ...
}
```

So when you first `observe` it, it's in the `NetworkResult.Loading` state - any posts you had stored have been wiped.

Your `Fragment` gets recreated when the `Activity` is rotated and destroyed - so if you're initialising the `ViewModel` data contents as part of that `Fragment` setup (like you're doing here) it's going to get reinitialised every time the `Fragment` is recreated, and you'll lose the current data.

You'll need to work out a way to avoid that happening - you don't actually want to do that clear-and-fetch whenever a `Fragment` is created, so you'll have to decide when it *should* happen. Maybe when the `ViewModel` is first created (i.e. through the `init` block), maybe the *first* time a `Fragment` calls it (e.g. create an *initialised* boolean in the VM set to *false*, check it in the call, set *true* when it runs). Or maybe just when `postsResponse` has no value yet (`postsResponse.value == null`). I don't know the flow of your application so you'll have to work out when to force a fetch and when to keep the data that's already there

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, sorry about too long codes, I tried to make it shorter and related to the problem only, but I should add both ViewModel and fragment to know why this problem happens,
after doing one edit like you suggest `if(postsResponse.value == null) {
            postsResponse.value = NetworkResult.Loading()
        }`

I succeed to load the same data but when rotate I see the screen is flickering (it's a bad experience for the user I guessed this happens by default in AsyncListDiffer I'll search about how to disable animation)

Comment: also sometimes it fails to get data again and calls `postViewModel.getPostListByLabel()` again Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: @DrMido it's down to your code's logic whether the data gets fetched again or not - the ViewModel isn't destroyed, so if your recreated Fragment just calls `postsResponse.observe` it'll get the current data. Register that observer early enough (e.g. in `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` - don't register it in `requestApiData`) and it should display fine. Then it's up to you whether you refresh that data (which you're currently doing after `onStart` thanks to that `launchWhileStarted` call). I can't tell you how to decide on that logic though